# What is the best (and most secure) way to store private keys in an Express server?

Tags: wallet, security, private-key, javascript, seed-phrase

I'm working on a server that will have access to a specific wallet that hold funds and NFTs to submit transactions. Therefore, it will have to manage private keys.

I'm thinking of storing them encrypted as environment variables (`.env` file), using RSA encryption.

Is this a good practice or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this post, [Best setup of your air-gapped offline machine (cold environment)?](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/questions/2576/best-setup-of-your-air-gapped-offline-machine-cold-environment/4880#4880).

Also consider the following https://cosd.com/frankenwallet.